# How can I mount a cifs share as a volume from a rootless podman container?

Tags: mount, cifs, container, smb, podman

Say I create a named volume

```
podman volume create --opt type=cifs --opt o=async --opt device=//mynas.lan/steamcache steamcache
```

According to `podman volume inspect`, this volume's mountpoint is

```
/home/me/.local/share/containers/storage/volumes/steamcache/_data
```

So in order to allow mounting this without root permissions, I add this to `/etc/fstab`:

```
//mynas.lan/steamcache /home/me/.local/share/containers/storage/volumes/steamcache/_data cifs noauto,user 0 0
```

This works when I manually mount it:

```
mount /home/me/.local/share/containers/storage/volumes/steamcache/_data
```

It asks me for the smb password, then mounts the folder correctly without ever needing to escalate permissions.

However, when I start a podman container that uses this volume, it asks me for the smb password, then says

```
Error: error mounting volume steamcache for container 49da929a55753c244cae62244c2bb5417013a37785667d1d138026a4e1d48163: mount error(1): Operation not permitted
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
mount: permission denied (are you root?)
```

What am I doing wrong here?